# to_string(42) more than one instance matches the argument

Tags: c++, ambiguity

Exacly as in the subject I use VS2010:

I have:

`std::string s = std::to_string(42);`

and the error

```
Error   4   error C2668: 'std::to_string' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

how to repair it?

Comment: Yes...................

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual C++ 2010 has only three overloads for `std::to_string` that take `long long`, `unsigned long long`, and `long double`. The standard defines more than that, but VC++ 2010 doesn't support them. No conversion from the `int` literal `42` is preferred, so the call is ambiguous. Instead, you can use a different type of integer literal. For example:

```
std::string s = std::to_string(42LL);
```

Comment: 42LL would be more aesthetically pleasing, IMO.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I have no idea why I didn't do that. Thanks.